# What does Kierkegaard mean by 'spirit' in the following passage from "A Sickness unto Death"?

Tags: metaphysics, kierkegaard

Soren Kierkegaard- "Sickness unto Death", (Princeton University Press 1983)
1848- From- Chapter 1- That 'despair' is the 'Sickness unto Death'- p 9

> Man is a spirit. But what is spirit? Spirit is the self. But what is the self? The self is a relation which relates itself to its own self, or it is that in the relation [which accounts for it] that the relation relates itself to its own self; the self is not the relation but [consists in the fact] that the relation relates itself to its own self. Man is a synthesis of the infinite and the finite, of the temporal and the eternal, of freedom and necessity, in short it is a synthesis. A synthesis is a relation between two factors. So regarded, man is not yet a self.
>   …Such a relation which relates itself to its own self (that is to say, a self) must either have constituted itself or have been constituted by another.

Comment: "Trying to define yourself is like trying to bite your own teeth." [Alan Watts] https://www.etymonline.com/word/self#etymonline_v_23134 Etymologically the self is that which yours alone. Your own thoughts and feelings, in contrast with those of others.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to understand about spirit? (Danish: "Mennesket er Aand.") from http://sks.dk/SD/txt.xml

Comment: Kierkegaard describes the self as a tension. This tension represents a universal and perennial struggle for humans to somehow resolve the dichotomy between their spiritual and 'animal' natures. He terms despair as a 'refusing to become'. In light of this why does he term the 'self' or man as a 'spirit'?

Comment: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2185/kierkegaard-and-the-tripartite-theory-of-man?rq=1 https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/45408/what-does-kierkegaard-think-the-self-is?rq=1

Comment: *Man is a synthesis of the infinite and the finite.* https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/2-Corinthians-Chapter-3/ *...when [the mind] shall turn to the Lord, the veil [of intellectual blindness] shall be taken away. Now the Lord is that Spirit: and where the Spirit of the Lord is, there is liberty. But we all, with open face beholding as in a glass the glory of the Lord, are changed into the same image from glory to glory, even as by the Spirit of the Lord.* The tension is in the **surrender** of the individual self to the infinite spirit of God. To identify ourselves with the divine nature.

Comment: @bread- Thank you very much. This response takes me by [pleasant] surprise! Can you please help me to understand what brought this response to mind in terms of my question and how you selected it? Regards, CS

Comment: @CharlesMSaunders It probably should have been obvious to me since I've always found the subject matter so interesting, but I really struggled awhile with this question until finally my intuition kicked in. I suddenly realized the key statement there is "Man is a synthesis of the infinite and the finite". That was Kierkegaard's way of re-stating the truth. The particular bible verse just happens to be one of my favorites, because it is so profoundly philosophical, imho.

Comment: @Bread- For me the similarity in the phrasing and even the 'message' between SK's piece on 'spirit' and the 'bible' quotation leads me to ask you if that appears to be the case to you and to ask you what is your take on why the similarity? Regards, CS

Comment: @CharlesMSaunders Yes, I believe so. Probably because he was a Protestant theologian with a brilliant mind capable of recognizing and communicating universal truths.